# Symbol lookup error for libreadline

Tags: ubuntu, readline, symbol-table

I recently started having problems with running programs like sqlite3 or awk on Ubuntu20.
These programs won't start and just show this error:
`symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.8: undefined symbol: UP`

I found several solutions but those usually lead to installing libreadline from source. I removed libreadline and libhistory and their symlinks from /usr/local and followed a guide that is not available online now.

I installed it, made all symlinks, updated ENV variables but the problem still persists.

These solutions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670417/how-to-compile-readline-from-source and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881581/libreadline-so-7-undefined-symbol-up ) suggest that invalid symbol may be defined here /usr/lib/libncurses.so but tsuch file is not in my system.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions what I can do to fix this problem.

Comment: Maybe it's in a different location now; the question you referenced is 6+ years old. On my Mint 20 system, it's in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Comment: The installation guide worked when ./configure had been run with --enable-shared option.(```./configure --prefix=/usr/local/readline/8_0 --enable-shared```)

Comment: I removed my locally installed libreadline.so from the $HOME/.local/lib folder and it awk started to work.

Comment: https://noknow.info/it/os/install_readline_from_source now redirects to an entirely useless website

Comment: @mcmuffin6o the content on the web site has changed since my original post so I removed the reference.